# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED (dynamic array)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm writing a program that dynamically allocates an array, on the heap, fills it with random numbers from 55-99 and prints them out in 10 rows. I'm using 9 more dynamic arrays to store each of these rows. But when running the program I get the error: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED after normal block. I'm sorry for the chunky code.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int numScores = 199;

int* randomTestScores = new int[numScores];

void fillArray() {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 199; i++) {

        const int min_Value = 55;
        const int max_Value = 99;

        randomTestScores[i] = (rand() % (max_Value - min_Value + 1)) + min_Value;

    }

}

void sortArray() { std::sort(randomTestScores, randomTestScores + numScores); }

// Created better varibale names than a, b, c, etc.

int s5559 = 0, l5559 = 0;
int s6064 = 0, l6064 = 0;
int s6569 = 0, l6569 = 0;
int s7074 = 0, l7074 = 0;
int s7579 = 0, l7579 = 0;
int s8084 = 0, l8084 = 0;
int s8589 = 0, l8589 = 0;
int s9094 = 0, l9094 = 0;
int s9599 = 0, l9599 = 0;


int main() {

    srand(time(0));

    fillArray();
    sortArray();

    // Delete this later
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) {

        cout << randomTestScores[i] << endl;

    }

    //

    for (int i = 0; i < numScores;  i++) {

        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 55 && randomTestScores[i] <= 59) { s5559++; }
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 60 && randomTestScores[i] <= 64) { s6064++; }
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 65 && randomTestScores[i] <= 69) { s6569++; }
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 70 && randomTestScores[i] <= 74) { s7074++; }
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 75 && randomTestScores[i] <= 79) { s7579++; }
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 80 && randomTestScores[i] <= 84) { s8084++; }
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 85 && randomTestScores[i] <= 89) { s8589++; }
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 90 && randomTestScores[i] <= 94) { s9094++; }
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 95 && randomTestScores[i] <= 99) { s9599++; }

    }

    int* testScores5559 = new int[s5559];
    int* testScores6064 = new int[s6064];
    int* testScores6569 = new int[s6569];
    int* testScores7074 = new int[s7074];
    int* testScores7579 = new int[s7579];
    int* testScores8084 = new int[s8084];
    int* testScores8589 = new int[s8589];
    int* testScores9094 = new int[s9094];
    int* testScores9599 = new int[s9599];

    for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) {

        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 55 && randomTestScores[i] <= 59) {*(testScores5559 + l5559) = randomTestScores[i]; l5559++;} 
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 60 && randomTestScores[i] <= 64) {*(testScores6064 + l6064) = randomTestScores[i]; l6064++;}
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 65 && randomTestScores[i] <= 69) {*(testScores6569 + l6569) = randomTestScores[i]; l6569++;}
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 70 && randomTestScores[i] <= 74) {*(testScores7074 + l7074) = randomTestScores[i]; l7074++;}
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 75 && randomTestScores[i] <= 79) {*(testScores7579 + l7579) = randomTestScores[i]; l7579++;}
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 80 && randomTestScores[i] <= 84) {*(testScores7579 + l8084) = randomTestScores[i]; l8084++;}
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 85 && randomTestScores[i] <= 89) {*(testScores7579 + l8589) = randomTestScores[i]; l8589++;}
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 90 && randomTestScores[i] <= 94) {*(testScores7579 + l9094) = randomTestScores[i]; l9094++;}
        if (randomTestScores[i] >= 95 && randomTestScores[i] <= 99) {*(testScores7579 + l9599) = randomTestScores[i]; l9599++;}

    }

    delete []randomTestScores;
    delete []testScores5559;
    delete []testScores6064;
    delete []testScores6569;
    delete []testScores7074;
    delete []testScores7579;
    delete []testScores8084;
    delete []testScores8589;
    delete []testScores9094;
    delete []testScores9599;

    return 0;

/*
    if (randomTestScores[i] >= 55 && randomTestScores[i] <= 59) {

        *(testScores5559 + l5559) = randomTestScores[i];
        cout << *(testScores5559 + l5559) << endl;
        l5559++;

    }
*/

}```
````

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<int>` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`?

Comment: Heap corruption is usually an indicator of some mismatch between `new` and `delete`.

Comment: I don't know how to use vectors, but if using vectors would fix my problem, I'd love to learn how.

Comment: You can look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector there's a simple example at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It may not fix your problem, but vector has a lot more facilities available (such as `vector::at()`) that aid in finding what the issue is.  Raw pointers and `new[]` has no such facilities -- you're just left in the wild with bad pointer usage, seg faults, etc.

Comment: I'd just prefer to not use vectors, I just don't see what I've screwed up in my code.

Comment: You have some incorrect variable names in the cases that add scores for scores >= 80.

Comment: @Sherixn -- Instead of 9 separate arrays and then, as mentioned, having incorrect variable names, you could have had a single array of arrays and access the array by using an index.  Then mistakes like that are lessened, if not eliminated.

Comment: Thank you so, so much @1201ProgramAlarm!!! You're a lifesaver! No wonder it wasn't working! Thank you once again!!!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will apply this to my future programs. I've been taking a course for 3 months now and am still learning the basics. This is my second week of arrays. I'll totally look into vectors and the links you sent. Thank you all for your help, and I'm sorry for my stupid mistakes!

Comment: *...I've been taking a course for 3 months now and am still learning the basics...*  That's the problem with a lot of courses that teach "the basics", but what they are teaching is [C using C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk), and what they present as "the basics" are really "the advanced, which you probably want to avoid in real code as much as possible, and shouldn't even learn about it until you've had 4 years of C++ experience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in these statements

```
if (randomTestScores[i] >= 80 && randomTestScores[i] <= 84) {*(testScores7579 + l8084) = randomTestScores[i]; l8084++;}
if (randomTestScores[i] >= 85 && randomTestScores[i] <= 89) {*(testScores7579 + l8589) = randomTestScores[i]; l8589++;}
if (randomTestScores[i] >= 90 && randomTestScores[i] <= 94) {*(testScores7579 + l9094) = randomTestScores[i]; l9094++;}
if (randomTestScores[i] >= 95 && randomTestScores[i] <= 99) {*(testScores7579 + l9599) = randomTestScores[i]; l9599++;}
```

There is used the same array for different indices.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm already mentioned this, but thank you for going the step further to show me where! :)